# How to enable users to adjust the volume of a video in html?

Tags: html, video

I am now creating a website which contains a video in the index page. I would like to use `<video>` tag to contain the video. However, users cannot adjust the volume of the video by themselves. I have searched on the internet but no results found. How can I enable this function? Thank you very much!

Comment: Provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Return the volume property:

```
videoObject.volume
```

Set the volume property:

```
videoObject.volume = number



Specifies the audio volume of the video. Must be a number between 0.0 to 1.0
   Example values:
   1.0 is highest volume (100%. This is default)
   0.5 is half volume (50%)
   0.0 is silent (same as mute)
```

The volume property sets or returns the audio volume of a video, from 0.0 (silent) to 1.0 (loudest).

```js
var x = document.getElementById("myVideo");

function getVolume() { 
    alert(x.volume);
} 

function setHalfVolume() { 
    x.volume = 0.2;
} 

function setFullVolume() { 
    x.volume = 1.0;
}
```

```html
<video id="myVideo" width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="yourvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="yourvideo.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

<p>Click the buttons to get or set the volume of the video.</p>

<button onclick="getVolume()" type="button">What is the volume?</button>
<button onclick="setHalfVolume()" type="button">Set volume to 0.2</button>
<button onclick="setFullVolume()" type="button">Set volume to 1.0</button>
```

[A lot of video player examples](https://codepen.io/search/pens?q=video%20player&page=1&order=popularity&depth=everything&show_forks=false)

Comment: Thank you for your solution. But it seems that the layout may quite messy. How can I configure the video player so users can adjust volume as they did on youtube?

Answer (score 0):

Here you can see demo where you can set volume

[Video Example](http://%20https://jsfiddle.net/hreb8xo3/2/)